# Why can't I add a click event to my button in the DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

So I created a DataGrid in WPF and defined such a button in my DataGrid (the name of the Button is Clear Button):

```
<Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}"
                TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 1 0"/>
                <Setter Property="Content">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <StackPanel Background="Gray" Height="40" Width="11">
                            <Separator Background="White" Margin="0,17,-1,0"/>
                            <Button x:Name="ClearButton" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontWeight="Light" FontSize="7" Content="&#xE71C;" Height="13"  Margin="0 5 0 0" Click="ClearButton_Click"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

Now I wanted to add a click event to this button, but when I want to start the program it says the following to me:

**"ClearButton_Click" is invalid. "Click" is not an event for"System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn"**.

So why cant i use a Click event and how can i get this working?

**Edit:**
My Full Xaml Code look like this:

```
Window.DataContext>
    <local:PersonsViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<StackPanel>
    <DataGrid HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Gray" VerticalGridLinesBrush="Gray"  ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="309"  Margin="110,76,58,0" x:Name="gridd" >
        <DataGrid.Resources>

            <TextBlock Text="&#xE71C;" x:Key="DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle.Content"/>
            <Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}"
                TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 1 0"/>
                <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="ClearButton_Click"/>
                <Setter Property="Content">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <StackPanel Background="Gray" Height="40" Width="11">
                            <Separator Background="White" Margin="0,17,-1,0"/>
                            <TextBlock Background="{x:Null}" Height="13"  Margin="0 5 0 0"
                        FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontWeight="Light" FontSize="7"
                        Text="{Binding Text, Source={StaticResource DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle.Content}}">
                            </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,0" />
            </Style>

            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">

            </Style>

            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="15"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>

        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" SortMemberPath="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" CanUserResize="False" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Id" Margin="3 0 0 0" Width="148" Height="17"/>
                        <Separator Background="White" Width="125" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="IDSearcBox" Width="113" Height="19" Margin="0 0 0 2" 
                                 Text="{Binding DataContext.QueryforID, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" SortMemberPath="Id" Binding="{Binding Name}" CanUserResize="False" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Name" Margin="3 0 0 0" Width="148" Height="17"/>
                        <Separator  Background="White" Width="125" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="Name" Width="113" Height="19" Margin="0 0 0 2" 
                                 Text="{Binding DataContext.Queryforname, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" SortMemberPath="Id" Binding="{Binding Country}" CanUserResize="False" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Land" Margin="3 0 0 0" Width="148" Height="17"/>
                        <Separator Background="White" Width="125"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="Birthday" Width="113" Height="19" Margin="0 0 0 2"  
                                 Text="{Binding DataContext.QueryforCountry, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>


            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" SortMemberPath="Id" Binding="{Binding Location}" CanUserResize="False" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Ort" Margin="3 0 0 0" Width="148" Height="17"/>
                        <Separator Background="White" Width="125" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="Ort" Width="113" Height="19" Margin="0 0 0 2"   
                                Text="{Binding DataContext.QueryforLocation, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>


            <DataGridTextColumn SortMemberPath="Id" Binding="{Binding Age}" CanUserResize="False" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Alter" Margin="0 0 0 0" Width="115" Height="17"/>
                        <Separator Background="White" Width="125"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="alter" Width="119" Height="19" Margin="0 0 0 2" 
                                 Text="{Binding DataContext.QueryforAge, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>


        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

My Method to Change Content on the Button:

```
 private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock textBlock = (TextBlock)Resources["DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle.Content"];
        textBlock.Text = textBlock.Text == "\xE711"
            ? "\xE71C"
            : "\xE711";

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(IDSearcBox.Text))
        {
            IDSearcBox.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to use Command? This maybe the xaml parser bug. You can create a new issue in https://github.com/dotnet/wpf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that the style is declared in the same class where it is used and where the handler is - try this:

```
    <Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}"
            TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 1 0"/>
        <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
                <StackPanel Background="Gray" Height="40" Width="11">
                    <Separator Background="White" Margin="0,17,-1,0"/>
                    <Button x:Name="ClearButton" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"
                            FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontWeight="Light" FontSize="7"
                            Content="&#xE71C;" Height="13"  Margin="0 5 0 0">
                        <Button.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Button">
                                <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="ClearButton_Click"/>
                            </Style>
                        </Button.Style>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: But did you know Why can't I find and address the button in my .cs file?

Comment: When declaring the name of an element in the visual tree of the Window, the compiler automatically creates a field named the same.
In the Code Behind Window, you refer to this automatically generated field.
Your name is set in Style.
But it is not part of the visual tree of the Window.
Just imagine, if your style is applied to several elements, then for which of them you need to create a field?
To avoid such conflicts, names in templates and styles do not lead to the creation of fields.

Comment: Okay and what should I do to Adress this Button in the .cs?

Comment: It's not easy enough.
We'll have to parse the visual tree of the parent element that uses this style.
And why did you need it?
Explain in more detail.
Perhaps there are other methods for solving.
And in general, your style is very perplexing.
Why do you need a button with another button nested in it?
It is very likely that you have overcomplicated something.

Comment: My goal is that when my text boxes are filled, the button then changes to a cross as the content

Comment: And why double nesting of buttons?

Comment: The easiest way would be to set the binding in Content and change the value of the property to which the binding is indicated.

Comment: The style you declared will be applied to the button.
After its application in the Content of the button, the button from this style will also be written.

Comment: Are you using MVVM?
Without this, it will be difficult to implement what you have in mind.

Comment: Ive made a new Question for that

Answer (score 0):

> My goal is that when my text boxes are filled, the button then changes to a cross as the content

You can change the style like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <TextBlock Text="&#xE71C;" x:Key="DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle.Content"/>
    <Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}"
            TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 1 0"/>
        <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="ClearButton_Click"/>
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Background="Gray" Height="40" Width="11">
                        <Separator Background="White" Margin="0,17,-1,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Background="{x:Null}" Height="13"  Margin="0 5 0 0"
                            FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontWeight="Light" FontSize="7"
                            Text="{Binding Text, Source={StaticResource DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle.Content}}">
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel Height="600" Width="800">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{x:Static local:Myclass.MyModel}"
            RowHeaderWidth="40">
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Change"/>
</StackPanel>
```

By setting the Text property of the "DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle.Content" resource, you can also change the content of the TextBlock in the button style.

In the Window method, where you need to change the content, you retrieve the TextBlock from the resources and assign a value to it:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock textBlock = (TextBlock)Resources["DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle.Content"];
        textBlock.Text = textBlock.Text == "\xE711"
            ? "\xE71C"
            : "\xE711";
    }
}
```

If resources are used that do not belong to the Window, but to a nested element, then they must be searched starting from the element of the event source using the FindResource method:

```
    private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is FrameworkElement element)
        {
            TextBlock textBlock = (TextBlock)element.FindResource("DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle.Content");
            textBlock.Text = textBlock.Text == "\xE711"
                ? "\xE71C"
                : "\xE711";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Ok but how can I change now the Content of the Button/TextBox when my TextBox is not empty?

Comment: I have supplemented my second answer.

Comment: Then there is the error message: textBlock was "null"

Comment: When and where do you refer to him?
It is created in the `InitializeComponent()` method; and do not contact him until he is called.
Also check the correctness of the key in the XAML resources and in the method.
They must be the same.

Comment: So I wrote what is in the Private Void method as you wrote it behind the InitializeComponent () with an If condition if TextBox is not empty then execute your method and I wrote it in the Xaml and the cs code as you did wrote it.

Comment: I've modified the example to include more complete implementation code.
I also slightly changed the style using the ContentTemplate property.
This prevents some possible errors.

Comment: I editet my Question that you can see my whole Xaml Code because it is still not working

Comment: Show your method in which you are trying to change the content of the button.
Is it in your Code Behind or in the ViewModel?

And specify which character you want to use for replacement (Unicode number).

Comment: I edit the Question and it is in the Code Behind and i just want an "X" on it after Change

Comment: I wrote the handler code based on the fact that everything is declared in the Window resources.
You are using the resources of the nested element (StackPanel).
In this case, you need to get them differently.
In a few minutes I will post the code for this using as well.

Comment: Added. Read on.

Comment: If you need to change the value only using the ClearButton_Click method, then you can do it differently - without using the TextBlock in the resources.

Comment: Thank that Code is working now but did you know a better Event then Click. That the button automatically recognizes when my TextBox is not empty and then automatically starts this if condition without having to press the button?

Comment: There are many options to come up with, including setting a binding to the ViewModel property.
But the topic has grown a lot.
Better to complete this topic and create a new one.
In the new topic, explain the logic you need in more detail.

Comment: Here i made a new Question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/67215522/15736779